# Identify completion of final retry by Polly retry policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, polly

How do I identify the completion (not onRetry event, but the actual execution and completion) of the final retry in Polly?

I could compare the retry count with max retry count inside the onRetry event, but the event is just the initiation of a retry which is yet to happen within the wait duration. What I want to do is identify the end of the final retry be it a success or fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I want to do is identify the end of the final retry be it a success or fail.

You can use Polly's [`ExecuteAndCaptureAsync()`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception) in place of `.ExecuteAsync()`.

`ExecuteAndCaptureAsync()` returns a `PolicyResult` object with `PolicyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful` or `OutcomeType.Failure` (among other properties covered in the documentation).

---

If sticking with `.ExecuteAsync()` rather than `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync()`, the end of the final try is identified (on success) by execution continuing to the next statement; or (on failure) by the policy [rethrowing the final exception](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works).  `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync()` is only a wrapper for those behaviours.